# Should I delete the question if I get a reference to answer in comments

Tags: discussion, answers

I asked [a question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/27725/state-value-function-as-a-product-of-sums?noredirect=1#comment44340_27725) in our main site and got a reference to the answer.

In such cases, it may be okay for me to delete the question and read it from the textbook itself.

But, is it an encourage-able act? Should I keep it intact, so that some other users may find it useful? Or should I answer to my own question after understand the answer from the references provided in comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think that a question can potentially be **useful** for future readers, you should not delete it, even when you have found the answer to your question in the meanwhile, because questions can also be valuable/relevant not just to the original asker but to future visitors of the site too (see the section "**Make it relevant to others**" [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Of course, if you have found an answer to your own question, you can clearly write a formal answer below your question (especially when you can add a different perspective or more info to what might have been already stated in other answers) or maybe just leave a comment under it to explain that more info can be found in another specific source.

In any case, it's up to you to decide whether you want or not to delete your question, so [you can delete your question, provided that nobody has yet given an answer that has already been upvoted](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions).

Note that [the specific post that you are mentioning](https://ai.stackexchange.com/posts/27725/timeline#history_b82d8867-5da2-48c9-8b56-ac1a12196a3b) has become a [hot post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60756), so you should really not delete it, as the system has detected that it can potentially be interesting to more people, and you can't also delete it because an upvoted answer has already been given (at this point, you could request a moderator to delete it, but I wouldn't advise you to do it for the reasons just mentioned above).